# How to get scp to copy the file instead of its symlink

Tags: symlink, scp

I want to `scp` a file to a server. The file is a symbolic link, and actually what I want to do is copy the source file.

I don't want to track the source file's path manually, because it can be replaced.

How do I get the source file's absolute path so that I can then `scp` with it?

Comment: Most `scp` versions follow symlinks by default, don't they?  You should check yours and maybe save yourself some work.

Comment: @jw103 Thanks for letting me know it. I didn't know. :)

Comment: Note: `scp -r` forces following symlinks.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Try this line:

```
readlink -f `which command`
```

If `command` is in your `$PATH` variable , otherwise you need to specify the path you know.

Comment: `-f` will return a path to a non-existent final target, so long as the intermediate link targets exist...  Use `-e` to avoid this, ie. `-e` will return null if the final target does not exist.

Comment: `-f` errored with `readlink: illegal option -- f` in OSX. Removing it worked fine.

Comment: @HeathBorders For OSX if you have homebrew coreutils installed you can also use `greadlink` instead.

Comment: On my systems, `which command` outputs ``which: no command in (…)`` or nothing.  How does it make sense to use `which` here?  What am I missing?

Comment: `ls -ln /your/path/without/slash/at/the/end`

Answer (score 30):

Under Linux, `readlink` reads the contents of a symlink, and `readlink -f` follows symlinks to symlinks to symlinks, etc., until it finds something that isn't a symlink.

This isn't necessary for scp though: scp always follows symlinks (it always copies file content, ignoring metadata except that `-p` preserves file times and modes when possible).

If you find yourself disappointed by what metadata scp can and can't preserve, I suggest using rsync. With no option, rsync copies file contents ignoring metadata. The commonly used option `-a` preserves all garden-variety metadata (times, symbolic links, permissions and ownership), and there are options to preserve exotic metadata like ACLs and hard links.

Comment: readlink do only single step for read linking. for example in ubuntu we have /bin/zsh , that is symlinked to /etc/alternatives/zsh , but this is second symlink. Finally we will not get real file or directory path. The same is with stat command. Only readlink with -f option do all resolves.

Answer (score 15):

Comparing the use of commands `ls`, `stat`, `readlink`, taking operations on file `/etc/localtime` as an example:

- Using **ls**:

  ```
  [flying@lempstacker ~]$ ls /etc/localtime 
  /etc/localtime
  [flying@lempstacker ~]$ ls -l /etc/localtime
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 35 Aug  2 22:41 /etc/localtime -> ../usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai
  ```
- Using **stat**

  ```
  [flying@lempstacker ~]$ stat /etc/localtime
    File: ‘/etc/localtime’ -> ‘../usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai’
    Size: 35          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
  Device: fd01h/64769d    Inode: 272202388   Links: 1
  Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
  Access: 2016-11-23 09:00:59.999887800 +0800
  Modify: 2016-08-02 22:41:26.090389904 +0800
  Change: 2016-08-02 22:41:26.090389904 +0800
   Birth: -
  [flying@lempstacker ~]$ stat -c "%N" /etc/localtime
  ‘/etc/localtime’ -> ‘../usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai’
  ```
- Using **readlink**

  ```
  [flying@lempstacker ~]$ readlink /etc/localtime
  ../usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai
  [flying@lempstacker ~]$ readlink -f /etc/localtime
  /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai
  ```

It seems like that command `readlink -f` is the best fit.

#### Explanation on the -f parameter

From [`man readlink`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readlink.1.html):

> `-f`, `--canonicalize`: canonicalize by following every symlink in every component of the given name recursively; all but the last component must exist

Comment: duplicates [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265856/318461) but is more elaborate.

Answer (score 5):

Stat will give you this information:

```
$ stat current
  File: `current' -> `/home/user/releases/build/'
  ...
```

Comment: readlink do only single step for read linking. for example in ubuntu we have /bin/zsh , that is symlinked to /etc/alternatives/zsh , but this is second symlink. Finally we will not get real file or directory path. The same is with stat command. Only readlink with -f option do all resolves.

Answer (score 5):

You can either do

```
readlink -f `which command`
```

or you can get something similar in Linux with

```
stat `which command` | grep File
```

If you are adding this to a script, inspect the error. If you don't want to see the error message in the case when the sym link is not there, go with something like

```
readlink -f "`which command`"
```

Comment: stat and realink without -f do only single step. then better call readlink -f  .

Answer (score 5):

I would use `realpath <symlink>`.

Probably what you call 'source' is the 'target' file according to the usage of `ln`: `Usage: ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME`

Comment: Thanks This worked like a charm!  with Mac OSX! where `readlink` didn't cut it...stupid mac. lol

Answer (score 1):

The following would give the full path resolving the symlink.

```
which [symlink] | xargs realpath
```

Answer (score 0):

`readlink -f 'which java'` didn't work for me.

But this did:

```
readlink -f $(which java)
```

Comment: Didn't work because it is `\`` not `'`..  but `$()` is better practice anyways.

Comment: Why downvote? My answer is an acceptable alternative, and, as the comment says, a better practice.

Comment: Most people who down vote do not also comment, so asking for an explanation of a down vote will rarely get you an explanation, because the down voter has already left and isn't likely to come back. I would suggest you remove the typoed code that does not work from your answer.  I would be willing to up vote if you took the time to clean it up and explain why `$()` is better practice.

Comment: As Stephen explained to you, ' is not ` . You should encapsulate by `command` , but this is deprecated. using $() is better, because encapsulation $( $(command) ) is much easier and don't need special escaping. Then it is preferred. In your first example you used usual apostrophe, then readlink is trying to find file named 'which java' with space in its name. But you intention is call command which with argument java, for finding java binary executable path.

Answer (score 0):

On MAC OX, "-f" parameter doesn't work, 'readlink' works without any parameter.

```
KZs-MacBook-Pro:bin kz$ readlink -f pip3
readlink: illegal option -- f
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]

KZs-MacBook-Pro:bin kz$ readlink pip3
../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pip3
```

Answer (score 0):

For macOS Catalina try -

```
readlink -n `which command`
```